# Ember, Ember Data, MongoDB _id and namespace

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ember.js, express, ember-data

I'm new to Emberjs and I'm developing Nodejs /Express/ app with MongoDB and Ember. According to [this blog post](http://dbushell.com/2013/04/25/ember-data-and-mongodb/) I added `primaryKey`, `serializerId` to my extended adapter.

```
window.Frontend.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api',
  serializer: DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    serializeId: function(id) {
      return id.toString();
    },
    primaryKey: function(type) {
      return "_id";
    }
  })
});

window.Frontend.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: 'window.Frontend.Adapter'
});
```

Everything is working perfect. But namespace not working for me. The request is sent to `http://localhost:3000/pages` not `http://localhost:3000/api/pages`. I don't have any idea.

Other resources for related issue:

- [Ember, Ember Data and MongoDB's _id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364630/ember-ember-data-and-mongodbs-id)
- [Adding New Ember.js Objects/Records when DB Provides ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392258/adding-new-ember-js-objects-records-when-db-provides-id)
- [Using primary keys with Ember Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821980/using-primary-keys-with-ember-data)

I'm using Ember 1.1.2 with Ember-Data 1.0.0.beta3. Thank you for any advice? If you need more info let me know :D

**UPDATED** If have similar issue go to this [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1509)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things have slightly changed in Ember Data. The following code works for me using **Ember 1.3** and **Ember Data 1.0.0 Beta 5**.

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: '_id',
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});
```

**Update**: Looking at the [latest source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/fe564801508765364648c2b8f04e12d76d09df6b/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L44), it seems `primaryKey` is now a String. So you can drop `serializeId` function, which by the way I don't think even exists anymore.